# Store the path of a document I just saved with Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I just wrote a simple macro where some user can enter some data, and then the macro replaces this input data into bookmarks of a Microsoft Word document, and then the "Save As" window is opened. As the file is saved, a log is created in another worksheet.

It works perfects so far, but I'd like to know if there is a way to store the path of the just-saved file?

I'm asking this because I'd like to add a new column called "file", for example, which contains a hyperlink to just-saved file. (I dont know the path apriori, because users can choose the path they want)

Comment: Can you post the code? According to what can I read this is performed in word vba, so why to tag excel-vba?

Comment: The form for data input is on an Excel sheet. With the macro, i place the data into a Word Document and i create a LOG with that data, that's why i'm using Excel macro.

Comment: Show your code in the macro

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [Application.GetSaveAsFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx) which returns the path of the saved file, and returns False if the user cancels it.

```
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog 
If varResult <> False Then 
    'Do something
End If
```